# nodejs TRX gettransactionstothis not working

Tags: node.js, trx

```
var url = 'http://ipaddress:port/walletextension/gettransactionstothis';
var reqdata = {
  url: url,
  json: true,
  body: {"account":{"address":"hex-address"},"offset":0,"limit":250}
}

Request.post(reqdata, function (err_trans, result_trans, body_trans) {    
  if(err_trans){
    res.status(500).send(err_trans);
  } else {
    res.json({"result":body_trans,"error":err_trans});
  }
})
```

the above function i got **body_trans** as **undefined** and **err_trans** return **null**.

but using url like https://api.trongrid.io/walletextension/gettransactionstothis is working fine. how to solve my probem.please give me some idea to slove my problem

Comment: try sending your request using postmen , see what response are you getting there

Comment: {"result":undefined,"error":null}